# recursive Number permutation Time complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

I came up with a piece of code that recursively generates number permutations but am unsure of the time complexity, does any one know what it is?

```
 private static void maketree(int i) {
        Node<Integer> head = new Node<Integer>(0);
        ArrayList<Integer> hasLeft = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for (int tmp = 1; tmp < i; tmp++) {
            hasLeft.add(tmp);
        }

        for (Integer t = 0; t < hasLeft.size(); t++) {
            head.addChild(hasLeft.get(t));
            ArrayList<Integer> start = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            start.add(0);
            fillTree(head.getChildren().get(t), (ArrayList<Integer>) hasLeft.clone(), start, permutations);
        }
    }

    private static void fillTree(Node<Integer> n, ArrayList<Integer> hasLeft, ArrayList<Integer> start,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permutations) {

        ArrayList<Integer> current = (ArrayList<Integer>) start.clone();
        current.add(n.getData());
        hasLeft.remove(n.getData());
        if (hasLeft.isEmpty()) {
            permutations.add(current);
        }

        for (Integer i = 0; i < hasLeft.size(); i++) {
            n.addChild(hasLeft.get(i));
            fillTree(n.getChildren().get(i), (ArrayList<Integer>) hasLeft.clone(), current, permutations);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say you are unsure about the time complexity. So, what are your thoughts then? Don't just drop code here and hope other people do the work. Start by putting up your thoughts, and see what then tell you about that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of using `Integer` or `Number`, use `String`, that will help you a lot.

And you can use [this from GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) code.

```
public class Permutation { 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    String str = "ABC"; 
    int n = str.length(); 
    Permutation permutation = new Permutation(); 
    permutation.permute(str, 0, n - 1); 
} 

/** 
 * permutation function 
 * @param str string to calculate permutation for 
 * @param l starting index 
 * @param r end index 
 */
private void permute(String str, int l, int r) 
{ 
    if (l == r) 
        System.out.println(str); 
    else { 
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) { 
            str = swap(str, l, i); 
            permute(str, l + 1, r); 
            str = swap(str, l, i); 
        } 
    } 
} 

/** 
 * Swap Characters at position 
 * @param a string value 
 * @param i position 1 
 * @param j position 2 
 * @return swapped string 
 */
public String swap(String a, int i, int j) 
{ 
    char temp; 
    char[] charArray = a.toCharArray(); 
    temp = charArray[i]; 
    charArray[i] = charArray[j]; 
    charArray[j] = temp; 
    return String.valueOf(charArray); 
} 
}
```

Internet is for help, take it, why just run in some complexity ?

Comment: the question was about time complexity, you should answer with the complexity, not with another code.

Comment: Ok, I will add that too. Meanwhile I thought I found more efficient code, that's why I shared.